# Efficient video compression for screen sharing?

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, screen-capture, libpng, screensharing

I need to know what would be the most favorable approach for streaming screen content and controlling remote computer (mouse, keyboard). *(I would like to build something like "one-click teamviewer")*

So my main question is about picking the video compression method for such requirements:

1. Most information between subsequent frames stays the same
2. Color depth can be degraded, but the details (text) must remain sharp
3. It should work on low-end bandwidths: 512k and below
4. Frames can be dropped

Comment: There is a browser-based screen sharing solution: http://guac-dev.org/. Maybe their code is inspiring.

Comment: lossless libx264 in rgb or yuv444 mode.